# Using CSS pseudo class before and after

Tags: html, css, pseudo-class

So I tried to experiment with CSS pseudo class before and after. I tried to use those pseudo to create header element.This is to reduce using div to hold left and right images. This is code for HTML

```
    <header id="mastHead">
        <h1><a href="#">Branding</a></h1>
    </header>
```

So I have 3 images to create traditional header element which is 20px width for left and right side with 100px height and for the middle, 1px width and 100px height which will repeat horizontal. And here my CSS

```
    #mastHead {
        background:url(images/headMiddle.jpg) repeat-x top left;
        width:1000px;
        height:100px;
        overflow:hidden;
    }

    #mastHead:before {
        content:"";
        display:block;
        background:url(images/headLeft.jpg) no-repeat top left;
        width:20px;
        height:100px;
        float:left;
    }

    #mastHead:after {
        content:"";
        display:block;
        background:url(images/headRight.jpg) no-repeat top left;
        width:20px;
        height:100px;
        float:right;
    }

    #mastHead h1 a {
        display:block;
        width:200px;
        height:41px;
        background:url(images/logo.png) no-repeat;
    }
```

So the problem is if I remove h1 element, it will align perfectly but if I put these element, it will push the ::after pseudo-class down and it will take leftover space according to it height.How can I make this h1 element to take just middle space without affecting the ::after space?

Comment: They are pseudo-elements, not pseudo-classes.

Answer (score 1):

I made a fiddle with your example: http://jsfiddle.net/3Dcw3/ (only set width to 500 to fit in a fiddle and set background to visualize them)

And here is a fixed version: http://jsfiddle.net/3Dcw3/1/

The points are:

1. Add `position:relative;` to the header.
2. Use absolute positioning instead of floating.
3. Add paddings so the blocks would position over them.